# Where are the high points in Zion (Honest Hearts)?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So, I just started Honest Hearts and despite beating the thing twice in the past, I've never managed to find all of the high points for Follows-Chalk's ability, which has a challenge attached. The question is obvious, can anyone tell me where they all are, other than the first one he points out on your way to Graham for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Follows-Chalk's ability is called "[Well-Stacked Cairns](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well-Stacked_Cairns)" and the effect is similar to the Assassin's Creed "Synchronize" ability, in that it reveals nearby map locations after climbing a high location.

The 6 locations that Well-Stacked Cairns works at are:

- [The Spine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Spine)
- [Ranger Substation Peregrine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ranger_Substation_Peregrine)
- [Ranger Substation Eagle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ranger_Substation_Eagle)
- [The Aerie](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Aerie)
- [Sun Sentinels](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sun_Sentinels)
- [Ranger Station Osprey](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ranger_Substation_Osprey)

The Well-Stacked Cairns bonus should pop once you've explored the highest point near these locations.  Each of the Wikia pages has a small inset map that you can use to figure out where you need to explore in order to get to these locations.